# Theano or Tensor flow as Keras backend on Mac

Tags: macos, keras, theano

## Background

When using the TensorFlow backend for Keras, I get the following type of messages

> The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX/FMA/etc instructions...
>       could speed up CPU computations.

When using Theano, I don't.

To install Keras I used:

```
conda create -n cv python=3.6 pandas scikit-learn jupyter ...
pip install keras
```

### My Mac specifications

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

## Question

Does Theano take advantage of those instructions or is it just not supporting them quietly?

Comment: So did the `conda create ...` line contain theano or not/was theano installed via conda or via pip?

Comment: The `conda create ...` did not contain Theano.
I believe that `pip install keras` does it for you.

Comment: So, if I get it right, you're saying that since I've installed Keras using pip, you assume that it compiled Theano during the installation, and therefore Theano uses the instructions?

Comment: It seems so from the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand - the second, i.e. Theano just doesn't support these instructions quietly.

First of all, to support such instructions, the C code should be compiled in a specific way for specific CPU, which you just can't get by simply installing Theano (or any other module) using pip or conda.

Also, there is a couple of things that indicate the same:

1. Specific fork of the Theano maintained by Intel which contains source code modifications to make it possible to compile [Theano optimized for Intel architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-intel-optimized-theano). Which you have to build (compile) on your computer.
2. They mention [in the documentation](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/140d0a064523349b630a284247c7cddd767fc46e/doc/sandbox/performance.txt) that "With a little work, Theano **could** also implement more sophisticated
   optimizations: ... * gcc intrinsics to use MMX, SSE2 parallelism for faster element-wise arithmetic".

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: the scenario below seems to apply only if theano is installed by something that compiles it, like, say, pip, and *not* with something that loads binary packages, like, say, probably conda.

---

While @Denis above mentioned the intel optimizations, https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4783 seems to hint that these optimizations are enabled at install time if your system supports it, otherwise disabled. From that thread:

> Whether to use these instructions is determined at package compilation time during Theano installation.

> it [Theano] runs much faster than Tensorflow.

Both of these hint that Theano supports it out of the box.